# Cutting Dimension in KD-Tree

Tags: nearest-neighbor, kdtree

Recently I have been reading about KD-Trees, where we choose a cutting dimension (Whether arbitrarily or by variance) to split the data and build the tree. 
Now am wondering is it possible somehow we can use, more than a single dimension as cutting dimension for KD-Tree? Like maybe use some kind of combination of 2 dimensions at each level, rather than one at each level.

If the idea is stupid, I would like to know why?

PS: I just want to know if there exists some related research or info on this topic which I can refer to, as I can't seem to find any.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting in several dimensions can be a very good idea. Have a look at [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), they split in every level in all dimensions. They are also widely used.

Comment: I will check it out and see if it helps me with what I am looking for. Thanks for the answer.